# Javascript functions an if statements

Tags: javascript, function

I'm making an Odd one out game and Im a bit stuck with the functions of it. 
(I have added an alert so I know that the image is being clicked on) 
So basically character 3 is the odd one out and character 1 + 2 are not the odd ones out. But when I click on characters 1 + 2 the same alert comes up as the one for character 3 (the odd one out). I've tried making new functions for the right/wrong answers but thats not working either. It's probably only something small but Im really stuck and any help at all would be appreciated.

This is the HTML:

```
<div id ="characters">
<img src="boy__pirate.png" class = "character" id ="character1"      onclick="characterclicked(1);" >
<img src="girl__pirate.png" class = "character" id ="character2"   onclick="characterclicked(2);" >
<img src="pig__.png" class = "character" id ="character3" onclick="characterclicked(3);"> 
</div>
```

This is the JS:

```
var oddoneout = new Array(); 
oddoneout[0] = {characterName:"character3", answer: 1};  
oddoneout[1] = {characterName:"character6", answer: 2};
oddoneout[2] = {characterName:"character9", answer: 3}; 

oddoneout.sort(function() {return Math.random() -0.5;});


function characterclicked() {  
if (oddoneout) {  
    alert("You're right!")


} 
}
```

Comment: `if (someArray) {` is always verified. I don't understand what you tried to do.

Comment: `characterclicked()`, according to your HTML, expects a parameter, while you have declared it to expect none. Besides, `if (oddoneout)` will always be truthly, because an array always evaluate to `true`. Can you please clearly explain what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var oddoneout = new Array(); 
oddoneout[0] = {characterName:"character3", answer: 1};  
oddoneout[1] = {characterName:"character6", answer: 2};
oddoneout[2] = {characterName:"character9", answer: 3}; 

oddoneout.sort(function() {return Math.random() -0.5;});

function characterclicked(choice) {  
// perform your checking here
if (oddoneout[choice-1].answer===2) { 
    alert("You're right!")
    } 
}
```

Comment: the function used to sort the array is wrong because it has no parameters, and mainly i suppose this is not a sort by a mixing of elements....

Comment: gaemaf, it does not matter as the parameters are not used

Comment: ok, but what is the sense of array.sort according to you? If i use the two parameters under IE i obtain a unordered array so i can guess... Instead, if i do not use the two parameters the array remain ordered so as created. Please, help me, thanks

Comment: I tried with IE11 and Chrome, both random permute the array

Answer (score 1):

Try to change characterclicked to:

```
var oddoneout = new Array();
    oddoneout[0] = {characterName:"character3", answer: 1};
    oddoneout[1] = {characterName:"character6", answer: 2};
    oddoneout[2] = {characterName:"character9", answer: 3};

    oddoneout.sort(function(a, b) {return Math.random() -0.5;});


    function characterclicked(i) {
        switch(i) {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                if (oddoneout[i-1].answer == i) {
                    alert("You're right!");
                }
                break;
            default:
                alert(i);
                break;
        }
    }
```

To unsort the array your comparison function is wrong.
So I tried to adjust your code hoping it could help you.